# c++ opengl camera movement

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am having issues figuring out why the camera wont move!  I think i setup the code correct.  Any pointers?

[image: Screenshot!]

When I launch it the triangle comes up but i cannot move the camera, most likely its my whole method behind the camera movement that is to blame due to inexperience.  Could somebody point me in the right direction?

```
include "stdafx.h"
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

//THESE ARE MY VARIABLES
//===========
int x = 0; //|
int y = 0; //|
int z = 0; //|
//===========

//Camera Movement

void glViewport(GLint x, GLint y, GLsizei width, GLsizei height)
{
    if (WM_KEYDOWN == VK_UP) {
        std::cout << "User pressed UP!";
        ++z;
    }
    if (WM_KEYDOWN == VK_DOWN) {
        std::cout << "User pressed DOWN!";
        --z;
    }
    if (WM_KEYDOWN == VK_LEFT) {
        std::cout << "User pressed LEFT!";
        --x;
    }
    if (WM_KEYDOWN == VK_RIGHT) {
        std::cout << "User pressed RIGHT!";
        ++x;
    }
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 1);
    glColor3f(0, 1.0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0, 1);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(0, 0.5, 1);
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 1);

    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10, 10);
    glutCreateWindow("McDank");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, take a look at how to do a question. Specially, [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You have not shown how you try to move the camera.

Comment: I would answer, but there are so many things that is lacking, that instead, I will suggest you to spend some time on tutorials, like, for example: http://www.learnopengl.com

Comment: You are never using `x`, `y` or `z` in your rendering code?

Comment: You have no code for the camera movement yet. Suggesting to move from legacy GLUT to newest GLFW.  Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040982/c-opengl-glfw-drawing-a-simple-cube)

Comment: Are you sure that this is the acutal code?  You have the definition `void glViewport(GLint x, GLint y, GLsizei width, GLsizei height)` that contains the movement code for your camera, and that can't be correct.

Comment: @Amadeus thanks ik there is a ton missing i just need to be pointed in the right direction!

Comment: The right direction is following a good tutorial in modern OpenGL, like [this](https://learnopengl.com/)

Comment: read [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)  and that  look into last 3 links in there. There are some C++ examples of player and camera control ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to register a keyboard callback with GLUT via `glutKeyboardFunc()` or `glutSpecialFunc()` to handle keystrokes.
- Your `glViewport()` function is...bizarre.  Not sure what you were trying to achieve here with comparing random Windows enums against other enums.
- You need to actually *use* your `x`/`y`/`z` variables in your display function, perhaps in a `glTranslate()`.

All together:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

float x = 0;
float y = 0;
float z = 0;
void special( int key, int, int )
{
    const float step = 0.1;
    if( GLUT_KEY_LEFT == key )
        x -= step;
    if( GLUT_KEY_RIGHT == key )
        x += step;
    if( GLUT_KEY_UP == key )
        y += step;
    if( GLUT_KEY_DOWN == key )
        y -= step;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( -2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef( x, y, z );

    glBegin( GL_TRIANGLES );
    glColor3ub( 255, 0, 0 );
    glVertex2f( -1, -1 );
    glColor3ub( 0, 255, 0 );
    glVertex2f(  1, -1 );
    glColor3ub( 0, 0, 255 );
    glVertex2f(  0,  1 );
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutCreateWindow("McDank");
    glutSpecialFunc( special );
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```